# Use different key store to sign the same application

Tags: android

I want to publish an app for testing in google play. Once I test I should publish it in my company domain .  Based on what I read in google you cannot publish a signed apk under two developer domain. So Can I use different key store to sign the same application?

Comment: I guess you cannot use two singed release apk for the same application. either you can use 1 debug sign or 1 release sign.

Comment: Use Google's testing tracks for this purpose. It has internal, alpha and beta testing available. Signing with a different key store is not enough. You'll need to change the package name(application ID) to publish the same app from a different account, keystore won't matter. You can even use the same keystore for both apps.